# Access variable names in call from dynamic formula in model

Tags: r, regression

Wondering if there's any way to access and/or store variable names in a call from a dynamic formula.
example:

```
run_model <- function(datas){
  model <-  lm(data = datas, formula = bmi~age)
  model
  
}

test <- run_model(nhanes)
test$call
```

Test$call does not include "nhanes" but "datas".

I tried searching through all of the parts of the model object and didn't find anything. Not sure if I'm missing something OR if there's a way to alter the call within my function to store the variable names.

Comment: Why do you need it? If you need it, you should consider having it somewhere else other than in the model. The model has nothing to do with the name of the data, but the data itself regardless of the name. if you are interested in the name, consider using `data_name <- as.character(substitute(datas))` after running your model. But I am not sure why you need this.

Comment: @Onyambu While I generally agree with this sentiment, do note that `lm()` (and other modelling functions) save the `call` precisely so that the original data name *can* be extracted.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it saves the call so as to run the model within the particular eenvironment. eg within a function, you can have a dynamic formula and data. and as long as you pass down the environment where the data is found, the original data name does not matter. Its the data itself not the dataname. You are assuming the function is just one level away from the global environment. What about when the function is nested within another function? You will not get the Original data name in the call object. The call is used for update as long as the environment in which the objects lie is known

Comment: @Onyambu No, that’s not what is happening here. The data is *also* saved, but that’s unrelated to the call being saved, and in fact saving the call would *not* find the correct data in the scenario you outline. And I can assure you that I am making no assumptions about the calling environment. In fact, I previously commented on Allan’s answer because it failed *in this precise scenario* (comment removed after Allan fixed his answer).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I must be missing something then. Though I am quite convinced that if I were to run a function eg `fun <- function(x) {mod <- run_model(x) };update(f(data))` using the solution below, I would get an error. also i believe nesting the lm call without taking into consideration the environment will cause an error. Thats why I mentioned one has to pass the current environment into the nested functions. Thus why i do not see the essence of saving the original data name. There must be a reason as to why OP needs that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph also running something like `lapply(split(data, group), \(x) lm(bmi~age, x))` stores `x` as the dataname yet the data represented by each x is different. Therefore does the name matter? I feel in a case like this, there is no name per se that would capture the desired data represented.

Comment: @Onyambu I need this information because I'm fiddling with functions that I will pass different models to (mira objects from the mice package). These functions re-run the model on a stacked dataset (as opposed to each individually imputed dataset) in order to extract a log likelihood for D4 log likelihood evaluation. I don't want to pass all of the model arguments to these functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `call` object is the literal call made to `lm` inside your function, and is captured without substituting any of the variable names used inside the function.

You can create a list of call arguments yourself and `substitute` the correct name in. Then you can invoke `lm` using `do.call`:

```r
run_model <- function(datas) {
  do.call('lm', list(formula = bmi ~ age, data = substitute(datas)),
          envir = parent.frame())
}

test <- run_model(nhanes)
test$call
#> lm(formula = bmi ~ age, data = nhanes)
```